# Submit Ajax.BeginForm via ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to submit an Ajax.BeginForm using an hyperlink as opposed to a Submit Button.  I tested with the submit button and the action recognizes the post as Ajax based by test Request.IsAjaxRequest, however if I try the following IsAjaxRequest returns false:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].submit(); return false;">Update</a>
```

Comment: Why not just stick with the submit button?

Comment: It is a requirement but I did find a workaround, I am using the link to trigger the submit button click.  I have the submit button hiding on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form is hooked into Microsoft's Ajax library, so you can't just call form.submit() because the wired up ajax events aren't activated. You have a few options:

- Use a submit button instead of a link
- Drop the MS Ajax stuff and manually wire up your ajax posts with jQuery (this would be what I would have done)
- Call the MS Ajax submit function

For the third option, instead of

```
onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].submit(); return false;"
```

Try

```
onclick="javascript:$('#form').onSubmit(); return false;"
```

But I've never used it so I don't know if it will work. You might also take a look [here](http://paululvinius.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/how-you-dynamically-submit-a-aspnet-mvc-ajax-form-from-javascript-and-jquery/) for the solution, as it sounds exactly like what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The `unobtrusive-ajax.js` listens for the form submit event -- so just calling `form.submit` *should* trigger the Ajax script.  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: @McGarnagle, it doesn't allways work. Inside the view a form.submit() call in the sense of an <input type="submit"> will work but if you do a form.submit() inside a JS file and target the form the unobtrusive-ajax.js  won't  trigger work.